# stoi() and stod() are terminating my program, I literally have no clue why

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert some strings from a file into integers and doubles using `stoi()` and `stod()`. However, I keep getting an error which terminated my program.

Here is a screenshot of what happens when I run the code I included below.

[image]

The variable `ageString`, which I am trying to `stoi`, is = `100`.

As you can see in the screenshot, it actually converts `100` into an integer and prints it out. Cool, that's exactly what I want.

But for some reason it is giving me an error saying `invalid_argument`. How is `100` an `invalid_argument` for `stoi()`?

I already made sure to `#include` string and to use namespace `standard`.

I've tried running my code on `code::blocks` and `Repl.it` using c++ 11. The results are the same.

I've tried using `stoi()` on a random number string (not from my file) like `1234` and it still doesn't work.

My `.txt` file looks like this (single space):

```
TEST NAME
M
100
200
300
1
```

```
//This is the body of my function.
//I've added several cout statements just to help me debug.
//In my actual function I don't plan to have any couts.

std::ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open(fileName);

std::string name, sex;

int age, activityLevel, calories;

double height, weight;

while(inputFile.good())
{
    using namespace std;
    string ageString, heightString, weightString, activityString;

    getline(inputFile, name, '\n');
    getline(inputFile, sex, '\n'); 
    getline(inputFile, ageString, '\n');
    getline(inputFile, heightString, '\n');
    getline(inputFile, weightString, '\n');
    getline(inputFile, activityString, '\n');

    cout << endl << name             //All of this prints fine,
         << endl << sex              //just like it's written in the file.
         << endl << ageString
         << endl << heightString
         << endl << weightString
         << endl << activityString;

    cout << endl << endl << stoi(ageString); //This converts and prints

    cout << endl << endl << "hello"; //This also prints

}

std::cout << "run this code"; //The program stops working here.
inputFile.close();
```

I expect the code to end by printing `run this code`, but it actually ends by printing `hello`.

Error message:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stoi"

Comment: `Exceptions
std::invalid_argument if no conversion could be performed` - it means that your input cannot be converted into int. You need to `try catch` exceptions when you use std::stoi

Comment: I'm trying to stoi() a string that = "100". Why can "100" not be converted to an integer?

Comment: If `stoi` takes empty string, this exception will be called. You should show the content of your input file. I assume you have there data only for one person. So your  while loop is wrong, because it executes twice the code and `stoi` takes empty string. After each getline you should check the state of stream. If it is bad, terminate it.

Comment: You have the same issue as in [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Comment: @rafix07 yes the file only contains the information of one person. (TEST NAME,M,100,200,300,1,)  This is what my file looks like, just replace the ',' with '\n'.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and show the varbatim input file and a [MCVE]. You could also put a `cout << "<" << ageString << ">\n";` right before calling `stoi`, which will show you what exactly you're passing to `stoi`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I added the `"<" << ageString << ">\n";` and it printed a blank value. I guess it is running twice like the the people above said.

Comment: @KandCpp that answers your question, a blank value is an inavlid argument to stoi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. \`while (!stream.eof())\`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code was iterated again in `while` loop. To ensure that it only iterates 1 times as expectation, please add more `cout` to check it. For example: I think your code will print `start reading input` 2 times then terminate your program. If it is, you need to consider using `inputFile.good()`

```
while(inputFile.good())
{

    using namespace std;
    cout << "start reading input" << endl;
    string ageString, heightString, weightString, activityString;

    getline(inputFile, name, '\n');
    getline(inputFile, sex, '\n'); 
    getline(inputFile, ageString, '\n');
    getline(inputFile, heightString, '\n');
    getline(inputFile, weightString, '\n');
    getline(inputFile, activityString, '\n');

    cout << endl << name             //All of this prints fine,
         << endl << sex              //just like it's written in the file.
         << endl << ageString
         << endl << heightString
         << endl << weightString
         << endl << activityString;

    cout << endl << endl << stoi(ageString); //This converts and prints

    cout << endl << endl << "hello"; //This also prints

}
```

Comment: For better stability, it is necessary to use `try catch`, because you read the file, and next you're trying to convert some text into an int. When you get correct values everything is ok, but when you will read some bad things from text file the program will fails

Comment: yes, of course, we should use 'try catch' for this case, my purpose is for debugging and hope we found the root cause of the issue, as it should not have exception with that input.

Comment: but still, it should have `try catch` :) Having various data you will not check every time what went wrong, and for sure the user will not check, so it's worth it to get an appropriate message and handle the exception

Comment: @theboy Thanks for the response. So yeah the problem was that the loop was running a 2nd time. Earlier in my program when it wrote the file, I made the last line of the file `outputFile << "\n";` This extra empty line in the file was causing the issue.